# How do I define a macro that prints the time it was defined?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

I have written a macro that is supposed to print the time (HH:MM:SS) of its definition:

```
(defmacro print-fixed-time ()
  (multiple-value-bind (seconds minutes hours)
                       (get-decoded-time)
    `(format t "~2,'0D:~2,'0D:~2,'0D~%" ,hours ,minutes ,seconds)))

(print-fixed-time)
(sleep 10)
(print-fixed-time)
```

However, when I run this program (`sbcl --script myprogram.lisp`), I get this output:

```
02:34:10
02:34:20
```

This is incorrect because both lines are supposed to be the same. What is wrong with the macro definition?

---

EDIT

If I compile before running the program, I seem to get the expected output (both HH:MM:SS are the same).

```
$ sbcl
* (compile-file "myprogram.lisp")
* (exit)
$ sbcl --script myprogram.fasl
06:15:18
06:15:18
$
```

What is the explanation for this difference in behavior?

Answer (score 4):

What your macro does is print the time at which it was expanded: in a FASL file that will be the time at which the form containing it was compiled, in a source file it will be the time the form containing it was evaluated.

If you want the time when the macro was *defined* then you want to use `load-time-value` to wire in the time at which the macro was loaded (which I take to be its definition time).  Because it's a macro this means that in compiled code what will be wired in to the forms which refer to the macro is the time that the version of the macro that existed at compile time was loaded.

You can also, of course, do the FORMAT hair at macro expansion time to make runtime code simpler:

```
(defmacro print-fixed-time ()
  (multiple-value-bind (seconds minutes hours)
      (decode-universal-time (load-time-value (get-universal-time)))
    (let ((s (format nil "~2,'0D:~2,'0D:~2,'0D~%" hours minutes seconds)))
      `(princ ,s))))
```

There is inherently a slight weirdness here: if you have a file containing the above macro and a function

```
(defun print-compile-time ()
  (print-fixed-time))
```

Then if you compile this file and later load the FASL, `(print-compile-time)` will print the time the file was compiled, while `(print-fixed-time)` will print the time the FASL was loaded.

Answer (score 2):

This macro gets the time with `(get-decoded-time)` at the time of its expansion, because the time is fetched inside the macro. Thus it will report the time when it was compiled. You want to do this:

```
(multiple-value-bind (seconds minutes hours)
    (get-decoded-time)
  (defmacro print-fixed-time ()
    `(format t "~2,'0D:~2,'0D:~2,'0D~%" ,hours ,minutes ,seconds)))
```

The time is fetched at definition, and expansion of the macro will always yield the same values.

Comment: Interestingly, if I compile my version (`(compile-file "myprogram.lisp")`), the program will output as expected when I run it (`sbcl --script myprogram.fasl`). Could you explain this?

Comment: That's because you're loading a .fasl file that's been compiled, and macros are expanded at compile time. You want the macro to register a timestamp at the time of its definition, by which you seem to mean the time at which the code is first loaded. That's why you should get the timestamp outside the macro definition. If you pre-compile the program with your existing macro, then the timestamps will correspond to the moments those macros were loaded. If the source code is long and the macros are expanded some time apart, you may see a few seconds' difference between timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

So I understand the "time it was defined" as the time point when the
macro definition was processed by the reader and compiler/interpreter.

This solution here will work even in the repl.

Ah I see now that this is more or less exactly the solution which @phantomics gave!

#### use lexical scoping to capture time point of execution of the `defmacro` form

I would solve it by using the lexical scoping (closure - in this case not a "let over lambda" but a "let over macro").

For that, create two helper functions `get-time` and `print-time`.
Then, using lexical scoping, we can capture the moment when the macro-definition is executed (okay, with some minimal delay delta between execution of the `let`-form and execution of the `defmacro` inside it).

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; prepare the helper functions
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

(defun get-time ()
  (multiple-value-bind (seconds minutes hours)
                       (get-decoded-time)
    (list hours minutes seconds)))

(defun print-time (time-list)
    (apply (lambda (hours minutes seconds) 
             (format t "~2,'0D:~2,'0D:~2,'0D~%" hours minutes seconds)) 
           time-list))

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; capture time when `defmacro` is executed by lexical scoping (closure)
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

(let ((my-time (get-time)))
  (defmacro foo ()
    (print-time my-time)))
```

After that, the macro call `(foo)` will always execute `print-time` on  `my-time` which was captured when the macro definition was run.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the answers, I was still a bit confused. I'd like to clarify the details, at least for myself and hopefully for others too.

A macro body is run during compilation. Let's see this. First, I'll write a macro for side-effects, i.e. no return value, but just print the time:

```
> (defmacro m1 ()
    (multiple-value-bind (seconds minutes hours) (get-decoded-time)
      (format t "~2,'0D:~2,'0D:~2,'0D~%" hours minutes seconds)))
> (m1)
10:06:57
> (m1)
10:06:58
```

It seems when I call (m1) from REPL, it is compiling and eval-ing, thus different output each time. Let's create a compiled code with a defun?

```
> (defun fm1 () (m1))
10:12:06
FM1
> (fm1)
NIL
```

Apparently the macro body is run while fm1 defun form is run, or an implementation dependent series of events occur. Let's explicitly keep the function interpreted.

```
> (setf sb-ext:*evaluator-mode* :interpret)
> (defun fm1 () (m1))
NIL  ;; <-- this time m1 is not compiled in to the function, we're interpreting.
> (fm1)
10:20:36
NIL
> (fm1)
10:20:37
NIL
```

And if we switch to compiling defun:

```
> (setf sb-ext:*evaluator-mode* :compile)
> (defun fm1 () (m1))
10:25:52
FM1
> (fm1)
NIL
```

Macro run during compile, as expected.

Now, let's rewrite the macro to returning a template form. This way the (format ..) function will be called each time we call fm1:

```
> (defmacro m1 ()
    (multiple-value-bind (seconds minutes hours) (get-decoded-time)
      `(format t "~2,'0D:~2,'0D:~2,'0D~%" ,hours ,minutes ,seconds)))
> (defun fm1 () (m1))
FM1
> (fm1)
10:29:46
> (fm1)
10:29:46
```

If one checks the time after defmacro form, after defun form and after fm1 calls, we can see that macro was compiled during the defun call (and time was set at that point, not during defmacro call), given that evaluator is compiling, not interpreting. If we're interpreting, then the (get-decoded-time) will be called each time (fm1) is called, giving different time.

Now it should be clearer why @phantomics' answer provides you with what you want. In his answer, the lexical form created by (multiple-value-bind ..) before the defmacro has to be run once during evaluation of that line, creating a closure with defmacro, regardless of whether evaluator-mode is compile or interpret.